# Elixir Wallaby crashes on mix test

Tags: debugging, testing, elixir, wallaby

I am trying to incorporate Wallaby into my phoenix app. I have followed the setup guide closely and made sure that phantomjs is properly installed, however on mix test I get the following error:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value:
```

My operating system is Windows10.
Elixir version: 1.10.1
Phoenix version: 1.4.15
Wallaby version: 0.23.0
Phantomjs version: 2.1.1
Here is the full output:

```
mix test

06:21:54.255 [info]  Already up
06:21:55.380 [error] Task #PID<0.486.0> started from #PID<0.488.0> terminating
** (stop) :eacces
    erlang.erl:2213: :erlang.open_port({:spawn_executable, 'C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/wrapper'}, [:binary, :stream, :use_stdio, :exit_status, :stderr_to_stdout, {:args, ["phantomjs", "--webdriver=55182", "--local-storage-path=C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/local_storage"]}])
    (wallaby 0.23.0) lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex:85: Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask.start_phantom/1
    (wallaby 0.23.0) lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex:28: Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask.run/2
    (elixir 1.10.1) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (elixir 1.10.1) lib/task/supervised.ex:35: Task.Supervised.reply/5
    (stdlib 3.8) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: &Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask.run/2
    Args: [#PID<0.486.0>, %Wallaby.Phantom.Server.ServerState{phantom_args: [], phantom_os_pid: nil, phantom_path: "phantomjs", port_number: 55182, workspace_path: "C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp", wrapper_script_os_pid: nil, wrapper_script_port: nil}]
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:wallaby, {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, Wallaby.Phantom, {:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, Wallaby.ServerPool, {{:badmatch, {:error, {:eacces, [{:erlang, :open_port, [{:spawn_executable, 'C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/wrapper'}, [:binary, :stream, :use_stdio, :exit_status, :stderr_to_stdout, {:args, ["phantomjs", "--webdriver=55182", "--local-storage-path=C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/local_storage"]}]], [file: 'erlang.erl', line: 2213]}, {Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask, :start_phantom, 1, [file: 'lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex', line: 85]}, {Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask, :run, 2, [file: 'lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex', line: 28]}, {Task.Supervised, :invoke_mfa, 2, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex', line: 90]}, {Task.Supervised, :reply, 5, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex', line: 35]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}}, [{:poolboy, :new_worker, 1, [file: 'c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl', line: 283]}, {:poolboy, :prepopulate, 3, [file: 'c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl', line: 304]}, {:poolboy, :init, 3, [file: 'c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl', line: 153]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 2, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 374]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 342]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}}}}, {Wallaby, :start, [:normal, []]}}}}
    test/test_helper.exs:5: (file)
    (elixir 1.10.1) lib/code.ex:917: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir 1.10.1) lib/enum.ex:783: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir 1.10.1) lib/enum.ex:783: Enum.each/2
06:21:55.392 [error] GenServer #PID<0.485.0> terminating
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:eacces, [{:erlang, :open_port, [{:spawn_executable, 'C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/wrapper'}, [:binary, :stream, :use_stdio, :exit_status, :stderr_to_stdout, {:args, ["phantomjs", "--webdriver=55182", "--local-storage-path=C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/local_storage"]}]], [file: 'erlang.erl', line: 2213]}, {Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask, :start_phantom, 1, [file: 'lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex', line: 85]}, {Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask, :run, 2, [file: 'lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex', line: 28]}, {Task.Supervised, :invoke_mfa, 2, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex', line: 90]}, {Task.Supervised, :reply, 5, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex', line: 35]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}
    (poolboy 1.5.2) c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:283: :poolboy.new_worker/1
    (poolboy 1.5.2) c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:304: :poolboy.prepopulate/3
    (poolboy 1.5.2) c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:153: :poolboy.init/3
    (stdlib 3.8) gen_server.erl:374: :gen_server.init_it/2
    (stdlib 3.8) gen_server.erl:342: :gen_server.init_it/6
    (stdlib 3.8) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.484.0>, {{:badmatch, {:error, {:eacces, [{:erlang, :open_port, [{:spawn_executable, 'C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/wrapper'}, [:binary, :stream, :use_stdio, :exit_status, :stderr_to_stdout, {:args, ["phantomjs", "--webdriver=55182", "--local-storage-path=C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/local_storage"]}]], [file: 'erlang.erl', line: 2213]}, {Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask, :start_phantom, 1, [file: 'lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex', line: 85]}, {Wallaby.Phantom.Server.StartTask, :run, 2, [file: 'lib/wallaby/phantom/server/start_task.ex', line: 28]}, {Task.Supervised, :invoke_mfa, 2, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex', line: 90]}, {Task.Supervised, :reply, 5, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex', line: 35]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}}, [{:poolboy, :new_worker, 1, [file: 'c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl', line: 283]}, {:poolboy, :prepopulate, 3, [file: 'c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl', line: 304]}, {:poolboy, :init, 3, [file: 'c:/Coding/Projects/BoomhuisOnline/boomhuis/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl', line: 153]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 2, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 374]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 342]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}
```

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The match failure is induced (although it is worth to report to the *Wallaby* project because they should not blow up when the process cannot start due to port access issues,) the real cause is the process cannot open the port here:

```
(stop) :eacces
    erlang.erl:2213: :erlang.open_port({:spawn_executable,
      'C:\\Users\\SARELV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/kz9cgp/wrapper'}, ...)
```

The port in question is `port_number: 55182`. I am not familiar with Windows, but this probably means that either *PhantomJS* has issues opening this port or *Wallaby* connecting to it. Does Windows limits access to ports for regular users? You might need to explicitly allow this somewhere in the OS settings, or like.